# Set user attribute to null or string.empty

Tags: c#, nuget, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to set the value of an Azure AD user to null or string.Empty, by using the Microsoft.Graph NuGet Package in a C# app.

That's my code:

```
public async Task<User> UpdateMobilePhone(string userId, string mobilePhone)
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.MobilePhone = mobilePhone;

        return await graphServiceClient.Users[userId]
            .Request()
            .UpdateAsync(user);
    }
```

If a set the value of "mobilePhone" to string.Empty I get the error: Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: "Code: Request_BadRequest Message: Invalid value specified for property 'mobilePhone' of resource 'User'.

And if I set the value of "mobilePhone" to null it's happening nothing because the default value of a empty user is null so he thinks, that nothing is changed.

So does someone know how I can resolve my problem?

Thank you in forward

Comment: Are you saying this user's `mobilePhone` attribute is currently null and you are trying to update it to null?

Comment: Maybe this link helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38704088/880990

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - yes this links helps. Thank you!

Comment: @Crowcoder - no the value of the mobilePhone attribute ist currently not null. But you have to create a new user object on which you have to change the attribute you want to update. And there the default value of all attributes is null.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear a field using using Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249131/how-to-clear-a-field-using-using-microsoft-graph-net-client-library)